# Detect language in pandas column in python

Tags: python, pandas, textblob

I would like to detect language in pandas column in python. After detecting it I want to write the language code as a column in pandas dataframe. Below is my code and what I tried. But I got an  error please help.

Thank you.

```
  data = {'text':  ["It is a good option","Better to have this way","es un portal informático 
  para geeks","は、ギーク向けのコンピューターサイエンスポータルです"]}
  # Create DataFrame
  df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  #get the language
 
  for i in  df['text']:
  # Language Detection
  df['lang'] = TextBlob(i)
```

[image]

Comment: You should include a whole error so we can help you with it.

Comment: TextBlob does not detect languages in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use langdetect library in Python for language detection.

```
pip install langdetect
```

```
import pandas as pd
from langdetect import detect

data = {'text':  ["It is a good option","Better to have this way","es un portal informático para geeks","は、ギーク向けのコンピューターサイエンスポータルです"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['lang'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: detect(x))
```

Comment: this is how you can do it for one column
`_df.at[_index,'language']=detect(' '.join(df.at[_index,'text']))`

Answer (score 0):

i think this will be enough:

```
#get the language
df['lang'] = df.apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x['text']), axis = 1)
```

Comment: this game me an error "TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'"